# is there road traffic accident data set

Tags: data-request

Is there publicly available raw traffic accident data set which includes the following attributes driver diet pattern,accident time,behavior and vision status.

Comment: "driver diet pattern", like what the driver was eating?

Comment: is he/she a vegetarian or non-vegetarian

Comment: http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/national%20household%20travel%20survey%20%28nhts%29 is your best bet

Answer (score 1):

No, crash data does not include driver diet patterns as the law enforcement office on the scene completes a standardized form that tries to assess what was the incident, who was involved, and when did the incident occur. You can get the accident time, vision obstructions (i.e. inclement weather, glare, etc), driver distractions, and condition of driver at time of crash (normal to DUI, emotional, ill, unknown), and behavior (what the driver was doing prior to the incident) from historical crash data, but each state has a different approach on making the data available. Florida's available data is scrubbed of driver information for privacy reasons, correlating the driver to known diets would require access to government records.

**Crash Data Example:**

[Crash data in Florida](http://arcg.is/1B4895j) contains the following [information](http://www.flhsmv.gov/ddl/ecrash/CrashManualComplete.pdf):

- Crash Date, Time of Crash, Report Number, County and City Codes,
- Crash location: Latitude / Longitude,
- Conditions which contributed to the incident,
- Vehicle direction, estimated vehicle speed, area of initial impact, vehicle owner and vehicle type, vehicle defects, injury severity, and driver's actions at time of crash.

**Example of State of Kansas Motor Vehicle Accident Report Form:**
[image: State of Kansas Motor Vehicle Accident Report Form]